# RestEasy method receiving null as parameters in case of POST method and working fine for Get Method

Tags: ajax, json, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I have created a RestEasy web service and were using **Get Method** and passing parameters to the services using URI like **http://localhost:8080/rest/search?name=foo** and were accessing those parameters by using 
 @QueryParam and it was working fine:
**Note: I am calling the web service using ajax call**

```
@GET
@Path("/search")
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json", "text/plain"})
@Produces( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public JSONArray getDetails(@QueryParam("name") String name) {
         //my code here 
}
```

My ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'get',
        url : searchURL,
        headers : { 'SM_USER' : userId  },
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
```

Now I have to change the method from GET to POST and in this case it is not accepting the URI paramenter now I have tried it in a different way like: 
Now I am passing the value through ajax data.
Ajax Call:

```
 $.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : searchSuppURL,
    headers : { 'SM_USER' : userId},
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: { 'name' : 'foo'},
    dataType : 'json'
success : function(data) {
```

Web Service Code:

```
@POST
@Path("/search")
//@Consumes({"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json", "text/plain"})
@Produces( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public JSONArray getDetails(String name) {
```

The data is now available to the Service but not correctly formatted I have sysout it

```
System.out.println("name...." +name);
```

instead of printing **name....foo**  it is printing **name....name=foo**

I am not getting what I am missing any suggestions...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I you want to simply get a String value, then just use the

```
@Consumes({"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
```

like you were trying to do. Get rid of the `contentType` in your ajax request (it will default to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. And add a `@FormParam` annotation to the resource method

```
public JSONArray getDetails(@FormParam("name") String name) {
```

Comment: Hi its working fine in local as I moved it into the DEV environment it stopped working same parameters are null any suggetions..